# Attaching node labels in spot instance

Tags: ambari, cloudbreak

I have setup a ambari cluster with my compute nodes as spot instances (AWS) 
I have also attached node labels to my spot instance.

The problem with the spot instance is that it may go anytime and hence my node labels also go away with it.

Is there a way wherein I can have my compute nodes as spot and whenever a spot shuts down and a new one comes up, a node label is attached

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cloudbreak, you can add tags as part of the deployment cli json. So, when the autoscaling/resizing happens it picks up these tags and builds the host with the same tags.
Example below:

```
  "tags": {
    "userDefinedTags": {
    "app_name": "",  
      "env_name": "development",,
      }
```